# Removing some lines from a CSV file based on a sorted list

Tags: perl, csv

I have a CSV file with ~175M lines (large.csv) and another CSV file with ~50 lines (small.csv). I have to go through large.csv until I find a line that contains the first line in small.csv and delete that line. Starting from there I need to find a line that contains the second line in small.csv and delete it as well, and so on until I reach the end of small.csv (all lines will be matched for sure in the order they are now).

This is what I was able to put together but I'm just getting the original file back:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy;

my $delete = 'small.csv';
my $file = 'large.csv';
my $backup = "$file.bak";
copy $file, $backup or die "Copy failed: $!";

open my $in_dh, '<', $delete or die "$delete: $!";
open my $in_fh, '<', $backup or die "$backup: $!";
open my $out_fh, '>', $file or die "$file: $!";

my $match = <$in_dh>;
while (my $line = <$in_fh>) {
    if (index ($line, $match) == -1) {
        print $out_fh $line;
    } else {
        $match = <$in_dh>;
    }
}

close $in_dh;
close $in_fh;
close $out_fh;
```

Comment: You don't `chomp` the line ending off of `$match`, so unless the match is at the end of a line, it will fail. I'm guessing that's your issue since all you said is "it's not working."

Comment: What he said. `chomp` before comparing to eliminate newlines screwing things up. Also, edit your post with more specific fault description and any troubleshooting steps taken.

Comment: Thank you, I added `chomp` but I am getting an empty file after running the script.

Comment: That's because `index(chomp $line, $match)` only `chomp`s `$line`.

Comment: Perfect, fixed and it's working!

Comment: You need to `chomp` lines from both file. As a style point the names `$in_dh` and `$in_fh` differ by one character in the middle making them hard to distinguish when reading the code. If the lines from the two files are expected to be identical then comparing with `eq` may be easier to understand than using `index`. Might the strings have other trailing whitespace? Perhaps calling `trim` would be worthwhile.

Comment: @AdrianHHH "I need to find a line that contains..." suggests that the OP is searching for a substring, not equality.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edits because they made your question no longer a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't `chomp` the line ending off of `$match`, so unless the match is at the end of a line, it will fail. You also don't check if you hit EOF when reading from `small.csv`.

Since your first file is small, it might be easiest to load it into an array. The following program does that and uses `$^I` and `<>` to handle the in-place editing of your file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @needles;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    push @needles, $_;
    last if eof;
}

{
    local $^I = '.bak';

    my $needle = shift @needles;
    while (<>) {
        chomp;

        if (! defined $needle or index($_, $needle) == -1) {
            say;
        }
        else {
            $needle = shift @needles;
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
/path/to/script needles haystack
```

where `needles` is the file containing the strings to search for and `haystack` is the file to search in.

Comment: Thanks, this ran very fast!